# Unable to add .mdf file in visual studio c# windows application project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

When trying to add .mdf file into my visual studio I am facing below error :

A network-related  or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error locating server/Instance specified)

Try #1 :- I already changed SQL server instance name under tools->options->Database Tools->Data connections to blank or default.

Try #2 :- Enabled namedPipes & TCP/IP & restarted SQLEXPRESS & SQLSERVER services multiple times.

Try #3 :- Created inbound rule under WF.msc with port - 1433.

I actually want setup file with DB because I have to install my C# application on client's machines. I don't want to go with the solution to install entire SQL server on their machines & creating tables/stored procedure with script as it will be tedious & everytime I have to install my application I have to do the same.

Comment: Is SQL Server installed and running.  Check Control Panel : Administrative Tools : Services and see if SQL Server is running.  You can also run SQL Server Management Studio and see if you can connect.  You connection string in c# should use same server and instance of server as in the login window of SSMS.

Comment: Yes SQLServer services are running fine. SSMS is getting connected. My connection string is : <add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=MACHINE-NAME\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog = DB_NAME;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>     Also my project is running fine on my machine.

Comment: So the error is the code doesn't work on a remote machine?  Remote machine doesn't need the server installed.  But the users are using Windows credentials because you are using  Integrated Security=True".

Comment: So for a remote machine to get access the Windows Account must be same on remote and local machines.  So the credentials the database is using should point to a windows Group that Account is on both local and remote machines.  And the users need to be in the group account.  For a company that users Group Policies there should already be groups setup and the database credentials should be using one of the established group accounts.  Talk to your MIS if you have questions.

Comment: Client doesn't have such database setup & they are not willing to do so. I need to create one .exe file which should get installed on multiple systems without installing SQL server. If my approach is not in right direction that adding .mdf file to setup then anyother way please? If I create the .exe of current project setup then I am unable to install it on client's machine, that's ofcourse as they don't have the same server as mine.

Comment: SQL Server Express can be downloaded for FREE and installed on any PC.  They either need to install the server or connect to a PC that does have it installed.  If they do not want to take that approach the you would have to use a different database with less capability.  I do not recommend use Access because it doesn't not support multiple users.  You can also use sqllite but that again has less capability and is single user.   You have to convince client that you are taking the best approach, or ask client what he wants to use for a database?

Comment: Here arises one more doubt, if I go ahead to download SSMS on one of the system & connect my application with it then how much reliable the SQL server will be in terms of security & safety. I mean using username & pwd or windows authentication, any one.. client or any one of them can login to SSMS & can play with the data directly. How can I stop that?

Comment: You could setup a single user database using a sdf file which is sql compact format.   But it has limited capabilities.

Comment: I would use Windows Credentials.  The SSMS can have multiple credentials.  Usually people setup an Admin account that has full Access and then a User Account that has less capabilities.  Both Admin and User can be Group accounts in Windows and then put users into groups.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/securing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Can't go ahead with .sdf. The data is huge(project is for a college) & other capabilities like generating formatted IDs, identity, stored procedures are required.

Comment: You do not have to convince me, it is the client that you have to sell the idea to.

Comment: @jdweng - I Agree, but what could be the reason I am unable to add .mdf file in visual studio & facing error : - A network-related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error locating server/Instance specified)

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with mdf file.  You can located Server Instance of Server.  So go to machine where SQL Server is located and using Control Panel :Administrative Tools : Services : SQL Server check if Running.  Then right click : Properties : Logon and try to run instance.  Your connection string should have same server/instance as the login window.

Comment: @jdweng - I did this, no luck! Same error :(

Comment: @jdweng - I got a new error after selecting Logon -> Local System Account. Error says - An error occurred while retrieving the information from the database. Login failed for user 'MACHINE-NAME\Username'

Comment: Was login using Windows Credentials?  Your connection string uses Integrated Security=True which is windows credentials.  So database is using a Windows credential but user is not in the same user group as the database credentials.  You have to check the database security logins to see what windows credential is being used.  Then add user to group.